# jquery php count loop on name to email

Tags: php, jquery, count

In form, I will be adding product info in. looping name eg. pname1, pname2 when add.
I realise now that when i wanna send to email we need the 'name'. what code should i put on php file to loop the pname?

*noted: my form and php code is not in the same file.
or i should put them together and click to loop?*

Php file put this?

```
<?php 
$x=1; 
while($x<=10)
  {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
  echo ;
  $x++;
  } 
?>
```

form in html

```
<div class="" id="" name="productlist">   <!-- Add Product Here -->

    <ol><input class="fpname" type="text" id="addpname"placeholder="Product Name"/><input class="fpqty" type="number" id="addpqty" placeholder="Quantity"/><input class="fpprice" type="text" id="addpprice" placeholder="Price per Item"/><input type="button" id="padd" value="add"/>
    </br><font color="red" size="1.5"><i>*Becareful when adding the Product, once added you are unable to edit the information except changing the quantity.</i></font>
    </ol>
    <ol id="addhereform"><input type="text" class="fpname" value="Product Name" readonly/><input class="fpqty" type="text" id="pqty" value="Quantity" readonly/><input type="text" class="fpprice" value="Total Price" readonly/>
</ol>
<ol><input class="fpname" id="fpships" type="text" Value="" readonly/><input class="fpqty" id="overallqty" type="text" value="" readonly/><input class="fpprice" type="text" id="overallprice" value="" readonly/>
</ol> <!-- Result -->
</div> <!-- Add Product End Here -->
```

jquery add button

```
var count = 1;
$('#padd').click(function(){
    var pname = $('#addpname').val();
    var pqty = $('#addpqty').val();
    var pprice = $('#addpprice').val();
    var totalpprice = (pqty * pprice).toFixed(2);
    $('#addhereform').append('<li><input class="fpname" type="text" id="pname" name="pname' + count + '" value="' + pname + '" readonly/><input class="fpqty" type="number" id="pqty" name="pqty' + count + '" value="' + pqty + '"/><input type="text" id="pprice" name="pprice' + count + '" value="' + pprice + '" readonly hidden/><input class="fpprice" type="text" id="totalpprice" name="totalpprice' + count + '" value="' + totalpprice + '" readonly/><input type="button" id="premove" value="X"/></li>').before('</li>');
    count++;
});
```

Ans:

```
$name1 = $_POST["name1"];
$name2 = $_POST["name2"];
$name3 = $_POST["name3"];
# and so on...

for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++){
    $productlist = ${'name' . $i};
    echo $productlist;}
```

Comment: The line `echo ;` is going to cause some troubles for you.

Comment: If this is now solved, please post the answer for how you solved it and accept it (yes, you can accept your own answers to your own questions!). Accepting a posted answer is how Stack Overflow manages solved and unsolved questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones help,
Here's another method(better) I just found. no need to type all the super long loop way.
Stristr is find name keyword.

```
if($_POST){
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(stristr($k, 'pname')){
        echo "$v";
        }
    if(stristr($k, 'pqty')){
        echo "$v";
        }
    if(stristr($k, 'pprice')){
        echo "$v";
        }
    if(stristr($k, 'ptotalprice')){
        echo "$v</br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should replace `if {} if {}` with `if {} else if {}` or with `if { ... continue; } if { ... continue; }`